# Displaying local storage in page: Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I am able to add to local storage and remove items but it wont display the added item in my html. Once something is added to local storage it should display on a favorites page, then when removed it should be removed from the favorites page. It is the viewing favorites section of the code that doesn't seem to be working.

```js
//Add Favorites
$('.favoritesbtn').click(function() {
  var storedbar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedBar'));
  var favArray = [];
  favArray.push(storedbar.id, storedbar.barname, storedbar.address, storedbar.description, storedbar.image);
  localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favArray));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));

});

//viewing favorites

var favBar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
console.log(favBar);

function displayPageContent(object) {
  if (object) {
    $('#bar-info h2').html(object.barname);
    $('#bar-info h5').html(object.address);
    $('#bar-info p').html(object.description);
    $('#bar-info img').html(object.image);
  }
}
displayPageContent(favBar);

//Removing favorites
$('.removebtn').click(function() {
  console.log('delete');
  localStorage.removeItem('favorites');
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
});
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? Is there anything inside `object`? gets the function `displayPageContent` triggered after the element are rendered (`$(document).ready()`)? Are the elements all existing?

Comment: Its inside an array

Comment: Are you calling your display function i.e. `displayPageContent()` again every time you add or remove objects to localStorage? I think you have called it only once on page load. You need to call it every time the data in localStorage changes, so that it can display the latest data.

Comment: How would one go about doing that i am bit of a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `displayPageContent(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));` every time you make change to 'favorites'.

I don't have your other code like html, if this does not work, post your other code. and make sure check your console log to make sure the data is correct.

```js
//Add Favorites
$('.favoritesbtn').click(function() {
  var storedbar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedBar'));
  var favArray = [];
  favArray.push(storedbar.id, storedbar.barname, storedbar.address, storedbar.description, storedbar.image);
  localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favArray));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  //update view
  displayPageContent(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
});

//viewing favorites

var favBar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
console.log(favBar);

function displayPageContent(object) {
  if (object) {
    $('#bar-info h2').html(object.barname);
    $('#bar-info h5').html(object.address);
    $('#bar-info p').html(object.description);
    $('#bar-info img').html(object.image);
  }
}
displayPageContent(favBar);

//Removing favorites
$('.removebtn').click(function() {
  console.log('delete');
  localStorage.removeItem('favorites');
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  //update view
  displayPageContent(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
});
```